# PyQt5 Enter Edit Mode Right After Insert

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6

Attempting to insert a row into a QTableView using QStandardItemModel.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel, QModelIndex, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTableView, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QAbstractItemView


class SclDataBrowse(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataBrowse, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(336, 462)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.view = QTableView(self)
        self.btn_New = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_New.setMinimumSize(QSize(70, 21))
        self.btn_New.setMaximumSize(QSize(70, 21))
        self.btn_New.setText('New')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_New)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.setup_ui()
        self.setup_connections()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.model.setColumnCount(4)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Record ID", "Starting Receipts", "Ending Receipts", "Billing Rate"])
        self.proxy.setSortCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.view.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.view.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(22)
        self.view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)

    def setup_connections(self):
        self.btn_New.clicked.connect(self.add_record)

    def add_record(self):
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        ndx = self.model.index(row, 1, QModelIndex())
        self.view.edit(ndx)
```

Cannot get the table to do into edit mode and I get an error:

```
edit: index was invalid
edit editing failed
```

Please explain what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have tried and patched your code and I have not been able to reproduce your problem, so the error is probably found elsewhere, and that is because its code is not an MCVE.

Comment: Question updated with MCVE.

Comment: Has my solution worked? If so, do not forget to mark it as correct, that is the best way to thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because ndx belongs to `QStandardItemModel` but edit requires a `QModelIndex` that belongs to the model that was established in view, and that model is the `QSortFilterProxyModel`, so you have to convert the `QModelIndex` that belongs to the source to the `QModelIndex` corresponding to the proxy with `mapFromSource()`:

```
def add_record(self):
    row = self.model.rowCount()
    self.model.insertRow(row)
    ndx = self.model.index(row, 1)
    ix = self.proxy.mapFromSource(ndx) 
    self.view.edit(ix)
```